# barman-wal-archive with -WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)

Tags: postgresql, barman

i'm trying to use "barman-wal-archive"
can't find out where to fix the issue or how to debug it, anyway
there is a brand-new barman 2.10 and it's log:

```
2019-12-16 10:44:08,908 [16653] barman.server INFO: Received file '0000000100000004000000A3' with checksum 'e3fced48b20b874fc34e89dc0ce87adf' by put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:44:08,913 [16653] barman.server ERROR: Impossible to write already existing file '0000000100000004000000A3' in put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:44:13,132 [16670] barman.server INFO: Received file '0000000100000004000000A3' with checksum 'e3fced48b20b874fc34e89dc0ce87adf' by put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:44:13,137 [16670] barman.server ERROR: Impossible to write already existing file '0000000100000004000000A3' in put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:45:02,234 [16725] barman.wal_archiver INFO: Found 1 xlog segments from file archival for postgres-server. Archive all segments in one run.
2019-12-16 10:45:02,234 [16725] barman.wal_archiver INFO: Archiving segment 1 of 1 from file archival: postgres-server/0000000100000004000000A3
2019-12-16 10:45:16,625 [16743] barman.server INFO: Received file '0000000100000004000000A3' with checksum 'e3fced48b20b874fc34e89dc0ce87adf' by put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:45:16,638 [16743] barman.cli ERROR: [Errno 13] Permission denied
See log file for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/cli.py", line 1355, in main
    p.dispatch(pre_call=global_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/helpers.py", line 55, in dispatch
    return dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 174, in dispatch
    for line in lines:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 277, in _execute_command
    for line in result:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 231, in _call
    result = function(namespace_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/cli.py", line 912, in put_wal
    server.put_wal(stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/server.py", line 1904, in put_wal
    fsync_file(item.path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/barman/utils.py", line 332, in fsync_file
    os.fsync(file_fd)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
2019-12-16 10:45:20,840 [16759] barman.server INFO: Received file '0000000100000004000000A3' with checksum 'e3fced48b20b874fc34e89dc0ce87adf' by put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:45:20,845 [16759] barman.server ERROR: Impossible to write already existing file '0000000100000004000000A3' in put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:45:25,059 [16776] barman.server INFO: Received file '0000000100000004000000A3' with checksum 'e3fced48b20b874fc34e89dc0ce87adf' by put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:45:25,064 [16776] barman.server ERROR: Impossible to write already existing file '0000000100000004000000A3' in put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
2019-12-16 10:46:01,647 [16827] barman.wal_archiver INFO: Found 1 xlog seg
```

postgres-server.conf

```
[postgres-server]
description =  "Saint Petersburg PostgreSQL server to test backups"
conninfo = host=192.3.2.1 user=barman dbname=postgres
backup_method = postgres
# backup_method = rsync
archiver = on
```

postgresql.conf

```
archive_mode = on
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_command = 'barman-wal-archive barman-server postgres-server %p'
```

by the way, when I issue barman-wal-archive on barman server it asks for password:

```
[barman@barman-server ~]$ barman-wal-archive --test barman-server postgres-server DUMMY
barman@ldn-postgres-barman's password:
Ready to accept WAL files for the server postgres-server

[postgres@postgres-server ~] barman-wal-archive --test barman-server postgres-server DUMMY
Ready to accept WAL files for the server postgres-server
```

a bit of postgres log:

```
2019-12-16 19:06:50.074 MSK,,,14552,,5df79de2.38d8,197,,2019-12-16 18:08:18 MSK,,0,LOG,00000,"archive command failed with exit code 1","The failed archive command was: barman-wal-archive barman-server postgres-server pg_wal/0000000100000004000000A3",,,,,,,,""
2019-12-16 19:06:54.306 MSK,,,14552,,5df79de2.38d8,198,,2019-12-16 18:08:18 MSK,,0,LOG,00000,"archive command failed with exit code 1","The failed archive command was: barman-wal-archive barman-server postgres-server pg_wal/0000000100000004000000A3",,,,,,,,""
2019-12-16 19:06:58.509 MSK,,,14552,,5df79de2.38d8,199,,2019-12-16 18:08:18 MSK,,0,LOG,00000,"archive command failed with exit code 1","The failed archive command was: barman-wal-archive barman-server postgres-server pg_wal/0000000100000004000000A3",,,,,,,,""
2019-12-16 19:06:58.509 MSK,,,14552,,5df79de2.38d8,200,,2019-12-16 18:08:18 MSK,,0,WARNING,01000,"archiving write-ahead log file ""0000000100000004000000A3"" failed too many times, will try again later",,,,,,,,,""
EXCEPTION: [Errno 13] Permission denied
See log file for more details.
ERROR: Remote 'barman put-wal' command has failed!
ERROR: Impossible to write already existing file '0000000100000004000000A3' in put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
ERROR: Remote 'barman put-wal' command has failed!
ERROR: Impossible to write already existing file '0000000100000004000000A3' in put-wal for server 'postgres-server' (SSH host: 192.3.2.1)
ERROR: Remote 'barman put-wal' command has failed!
```

This thing is that I see first WAL is received and then the whole process just stuck on that first WAL. and the same error message is reproduced again? How to define what permissions are missing?

I gave full access to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* to all users on barman server. Barman permissions seems file since WAL can be created by barman.

What did I miss in my configuration?

Tried :

```
[barman@barman-server ~]$ barman switch-wal --force --archive postgres-server
The WAL file 0000000100000004000000A8 has been closed on server 'postgres-server'
Waiting for the WAL file 0000000100000004000000A8 from server 'postgres-server' (max: 30 seconds)
Processing xlog segments from file archival for postgres-server
        0000000100000004000000A7
Processing xlog segments from file archival for postgres-server
        0000000100000004000000A7
Processing xlog segments from file archival for postgres-server
        0000000100000004000000A7
Processing xlog segments from file archival for postgres-server
        0000000100000004000000A7
ERROR: The WAL file 0000000100000004000000A8 has not been received in 30 seconds
```

it said - "not been received", file is in wal directory, but process is interrupted with error.
is it OK that we have 4 lines of "Processing xlog segments from file archival for postgres-server"

upd. i have cifs (samba) mounted and barman suppose to use it. It's the same open issue as here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgbarman/tickets/80/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did it! cifs should be mounted with **vers=1.0** just like that:

```
mount -t cifs //ipaddresofsambashare/barman /var/lib/barman -o username=root,password=superpassword,uid=barman,gid=barman,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,vers=1.0
```

Other 2.0, 2.1 and 3.0 - do not help.

uncool, but works

N.B. if you try to recover/restore database- all permissions on restore server will be the same as they are on barman server!

Comment: Caveat emptor: cifs / smb 1.0 is insecure, please don't use it anymore. Current is version 3.1.1 as of May 2022